# Wikipedia python api error, ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Searching from python wikipedia-api

```
import wikipedia
import json
wikipedia.search('Barack Obama ')
```

Got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 742, in _wiki_request
    return r.json()
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/panini-aidb/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have tried importing json as well but didn't work

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import wikipedia
>>> import json
>>> wikipedia.search('Barack Obama ')
[u'Barack Obama', u'Barack Obama in comics', u'Barack Obama Sr.', u'Barack Obama Presidential Center', u'Inauguration of Barack Obama', u'List of things named after Barack Obama', u'Barack Obama: Der schwarze Kennedy', u'List of topics related to Barack Obama', u'Speeches of Barack Obama', u'Public image of Barack Obama']
```

Comment: its just not working in my machine. there must be some dependency which I'm not able to sort.Please look at the error. Thanks

Comment: It's clearly not a dependency error though; you are just getting something other than JSON data in the request. You are not sharing enough information to tell why not. You should debug the code and see what response you are getting (just find the line with `return r.json()` and add something like `print r.body`.